# Iteratively add values to a row in a dataframe with discrete loops

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe with a column called "labels".  The data-frame is structured such that I want the label for the first 3 rows to be "A", for the next 5 rows to be "B", for the next 8 rows to be "C", and so on.

Assume there is no pattern to sequence such that the order goes:

```
loop <- c(3, 5, 8, 2, 1, 3)
```

And I want to assign to the data-frame some specific set of labels, let's call them

```
labels <- c("A", "B", "C", "L", "G", "X")
```

What is the best way to assign row values to labels in this fashion?  I was thinking of something along the lines of a double for loop, but it got messy quickly.

Comment: You need a for loop, you can do `rep(labels,times=loop)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
loop <- c(3, 5, 8, 2, 1, 3)

labels <- c("A", "B", "C", "L", "G", "X")

data <- matrix(1:(sum(loop)), sum(loop),1)

names <- rep(labels, loop)

rownames(data) <- names
```

using Lamia's comment :)

EDIT: Doesn't necessarily need `unlist(...)`.